# How can I send a statement to a PostgreSQL database directed to a character varying attribute?

Tags: java, postgresql

**The attributes in this code are supposed to be character varying in PostgreSQL but when I try to setString for every attribute it won't work so I think setString is not the right thing but I can't find the solution, any help?**

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "dob" is of type date
> but expression is of type character varying   Hint: You will need to
> rewrite or cast the expression.   Position: 139   at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
> at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)  at
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:130)
> at backendstructure.BackEndStructure$DBM.run(BackEndStructure.java:83)

```
public static class DBM implements Runnable{
        @Override
            public void run(){
            
            String jdbcURL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MedialChainDataBase";
            String username = "postgres";
            String password = "adminnhost";

            try{

                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            } catch (Exception e){

                System.out.println("Fail to Load the JDBC Driver");
            }

            try{

                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, username, password);
                System.out.println("Connected to PostgreSQL Server");
                
                String sql = "INSERT INTO patient (pat_username, firstname, lastname, gender, dob, phone_number, ssn, address, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

                statement.setString(1, "omar12334");
                statement.setString(2, "Omar");
                statement.setString(3, "Adel");
                statement.setString(4, "male");
                statement.setString(5, "1999/09/07");
                statement.setString(6, "+2010066673452");
                statement.setString(7, "5432642347556789");
                statement.setString(8, "Moustafa Kamel");
                statement.setString(9, "omarwqel939@gmail.com");
                statement.setString(10, "omarpassword");
                
                int rows = statement.executeUpdate();
                if (rows > 0){

                    System.out.println("New Patient Joined");
                }

                connection.close();

            } catch(Exception e){

                System.out.println("Connection Failed to PostgreSQL Server");
            }
        }        
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't execute the statement in the database, it goes through the catch before statement.executeUpdatte();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERROR: column "dob" is of type date but expression is of type character varying

You need to pass an instance of `java.time.LocalDate`, not a String

```
 statement.setObject(5, LocalDate.of(1999, 9,7));
```